# ACL graph hierarchical looping based on Vertex property

Tags: acl, graph-databases, gremlin, janusgraph

Here is my sample graph

```
    g.addV('user').property('userId','user1').as('u1').
      addV('user').property('userId','user2').as('u2').
      addV('user').property('userId','user3').as('u3').
      addV('group').property('groupId','group1').as('g1').
      addV('group').property('groupId','group2').as('g2').
      addV('group').property('groupId','group3').as('g3').
      addV('folder').property('folderId','folder1').property('inheritance',false).as('f1').
      addV('folder').property('folderId','folder2').property('inheritance',true).as('f2').
      addV('folder').property('folderId','folder3').property('inheritance',true).as('f3').
      addV('file').property('fileId','file1').
      addE('in_folder').to('f1').
      addE('in_folder').from('f2').to('f1').
      addE('in_folder').from('f3').to('f2').
      addE('member_of').from('u1').to('g1').
      addE('member_of').from('u2').to('g2').
      addE('member_of').from('u3').to('g3').
      addE('member_of').from('g3').to('g1').
      addE('has_permission').from('g1').to('f1').
      addE('has_permission').from('u2').to('f1').iterate()
```

- Folder f2 is inheriting from f1 meaning the users and groups who have access to f1 will also have access to f2, same goes for f3.
- Access to a folder for an user can come from a group or parent group of the group

How can i write a gremlin query to check permission for 'user1' have permission on f3 ?

Below query can fetch direct access to user or one of its group on the given folder where it doesn't check for parentfolder permissions through inheritance property.

```
 g.V().has('user','userId','user1').emit()
.until(__.not(outE('member_of'))).repeat(out('member_of')).filter(outE('has_permission').has('permission','VS_F').inV().has('folder','folderId','folder1')).hasNext()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using filter, just continue the traversal:

```
g.V().has('user', 'userId', 'user1').emit().repeat(out('member_of'))
.out('has_permission').emit().repeat(__.in('in_folder').has('inheritance',true))
.has('folder', 'folderId', 'folder3')
.path().unfold().valueMap()
```

We first getting all the group membership recursively.
Then getting all the resources the user and his groups has access to.
Then traversing all the inherited resources recursively.
Finally, filtering the required resource.
The last line is only needed if you want to see the relations that permitted the access.

Comment: Thanks Kfir. there is small correction in the query                           
          g.V().has('user', 'userId', 'user1').emit().repeat(out('member_of'))
.out('has_permission').inV().emit().repeat(__.in('in_folder').has('inheritance',true))
.has('folder', 'folderId', 'folder3')
.path().unfold().valueMap()

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. The query was correct as it is . After out() you don't do inV(). You probably used outE() instead.

Comment: Also, could you be able to help out on the query for checking permission on 'file1' ?   all the users who have access to folder will have access to files. the immediate parent folder is inheriting access from its super parent. Thank you.

Comment: And to complicate the answered question, lets just say f3 folder is inheriting access from f2 and f1 is from f1, along with inheritance user have its own access to f3. Meaning the folder have access in two ways. The above answer will work for this scenario ?

Comment: Yes. the above answer will return all possible paths.